# Java Update clause not updating sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am making a GUI and I need to update one column called "OCCURRENCES" whenever a patient needs help. I am using Netbeans (Java). For some reason I am not getting any errors. But My table does not Update. The `executeUpdate` is returning '0'. I have close all my result set statements and prepared statements at the end of the 'try', 'catch'.Also any other updates like updating from textfields, insertion of new patient and deleting patient from a table is working fine; just having problem with updating this column which initial value I have set to be zero whenever an occurrence happens I would like to call this method to increment value on column. I'm just learning to use sqlite, and I am really confuse please help here is the part of the code I am having problems with, Also it reaches the `JOPtionPane` message successfully.

```
try
{
 conn = javaConnect.ConnectDB();//Returns Connection
 PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE PEMs SET OCCURRENCES = ? "//1
          + "WHERE ROOM = ?");//2
  pst.setInt(1, 1);
  pst.setInt(2,1);
  pst.executeUpdate();
  int updated=pst.executeUpdate(); // get count to see if anything was updated

  System.out.println("OCC" + updated);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCCESSFULL OCCURRENCE");

}
catch (Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error UpdateOccurence :" + e);
e.printStackTrace();`enter code here`
}finally {
try{
rs.close(); pst.close(); }
catch(Exception e) { } }
```

Comment: you might consider sharing the exception stack trace...

Comment: Did you commit the update?

Comment: You've got a duplicate `executeUpdate()` in there, what return value do you get if you remove the duplicate?

Comment: What are the column values in the record that you are trying to update?

Comment: How do you create the connection? Did you disable auto commit?